# I can't compile the apk via buildozer

Tags: buildozer

When building the apk buildozer does not work. Issues errors. Help solve the error

I tried changing the buildozer.spec file. It didn't help

Below I have provided all the data about spec output. I can send you files anywhere for full understanding

buildozer.spec :

```
[app]
# (str) Title of your application
title = My Application
# (str) Package name
package.name = myapp
# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test
# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .
# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas
# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png
# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec
# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin
# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg
# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 1.0

[buildozer]
# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2
# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

[python]
# (str) The version of python to use.
version = 3.11
# (str) python-for-android fork to use. If not set, the default fork is used.
android.branch = develop

[android]
# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
android.ndk_path =
# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
android.sdk_path =
# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
android.ant_path =
# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET
# (str) Android version to use
android.api = 31
# (str) Minimum API required
android.minapi = 21
# (str) Android NDK version to use
android.ndk = 25.2.9519653
# (list) Android product flavors to create
android.product_flavors =
# (str) Android logcat filters to use
android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D
# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
android.copy_libs = 1
# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86
android.arch = arm64-v8a
# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
android.meta_data =
# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
android.library_references =
# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
android.uses_library =
```